# "zum großen Schiff": shouldn't it be "großem"?

Tags: declension

[In nthuleen](https://www.nthuleen.com/teach/grammar/adjektivendungen3antw.html), it is given that

> Ich gehe aus meinem modernen Hotel zum groß__ Schiff

However, "Schiff" is a Neutrum noun, and in the above sentence, used as a Dative case, so the declension of "groß" should be "-em" but in the answer sheet it is "-en".

What am I missing in here? I also checked the above sentence with grammar checker; the answer sheet is correct but I can't find what I am missing.

Comment: Note that *zum* expands to *zu dem*. Similar to the instance of *aus meinem modernen*, only the first takes the *-em* in dative.

Comment: @Michael so zum is a shorthand for zu dem. Do I understand you correctly? As a result "zum groß__ Schiff" is actually "zu dem groß__ Schiff"?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that *zu**m*** is short for *zu **dem***. The presence of the definite article requires that the adjective *groß* be [declined](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:gro%C3%9F#Positiv) weakly, not strongly:

- zu groß**em** Schiff (strong declension)
- zu**m**/ zu **dem** groß**en** Schiff (weak declension)

Comment: An example for the strong declension would be nice, but I did not find one combining *zu* and *Schiff*, either.

Comment: Sound a little bit old fashioned ... "Zu schnellem Schiff(e) gesellte sich behäbiger Kahn..." in describing fo example a meeting of all kinds of boats. Would this be an example for this strong declension? My rule of thumb was always "one M is enough" so "zuM grosseM Schiff" is too much :)